Spring 5 and Spring 4 Dependencies Across 2 Dependent Projects
I work for a company. I'm using eclipse.
I manage a project.
That project is dependent on a library that we built that manages all of the "Common Jobs" across all of our applications.
MyApp has a dependency to CommonJobs.
MyApp is using Spring.4.3.13.RELEASE.
SOMEONE on our team updated CommonJobs to use Spring 5.2.8.RELEASE.
Can MyApp actually use CommonJobs without updating to Spring 5.2.8?
I've tried running the job locally, and it did run. But when I deploy to our servers and try to run it fails. I don't how to explain all of the potential points of failure here.
I'm aware that there's a difference between Eclipse deployment assembly/EAR manifest entries (local) and Maven POM (when built and deployed to our server).
So I'm trying to get at principles with this question. Can a Spring 4 project be dependent on a Spring 5 project and still run?

It's a complex situation, and in the question some details are missing: 1) which error do you get when the remote deployment fails? 2) can you post the dependency tree of the library and MyApp? 3) which components of Spring is used in the CommonJobs and what has been changed for the upgrade, apart from the versions in the pom? 4) which are the environment differences (e.g., jdk version) between local and remote?
Have you tried branching CommonJobs from the commit before the upgrade and keep both mantained until MyApp can also upgrade?
